# Refresh EntityFramework connection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm changing EntityFramework connection string in App.config like this:

```
        var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString.ProviderConnectionString);

        connectionString.UserID = dbUser;
        connectionString.Password = dbPass;
        connectionString.InitialCatalog = dbCatalog;
        connectionString.DataSource = dbServer;

        entityConnectionString.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString.ToString();

        cString.ConnectionString = entityConnectionString.ToString();

        conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

But EntityFramework continues to use an old connection settings until application restart. Is there any way to force EntityFramework to get new connection string from App.config?

Comment: do you frequently make changes in connection string?

Comment: Each time it deployed via ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `ConfigurationManager` didn't cache stuff (though `Save()` might refresh the cache) the EntityFramework objects will cache the connection. In all likelyhood you need to release those objects and recreate them so it pulls the new connection string from configuration manager (assuming the cache gets refreshed) or actually modify the connection string on your DbContext object manually.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Travis is right.  Here is code I've used to do this:

```
public void RefreshContext(string myConnectionString)
{
  DisposeContext();
  Context = new MyContext(myConnectionString);
}

public void DisposeContext()
{
  if (Context == null)
    return;
  Context.Dispose();
}
```